# Storing input value to check wether postcondition holds true when applying Design-by-Contract

Tags: r, design-by-contract, assertthat

I make use of the `assertthat` package quite often to check postconditions in functions. When reading more about the idea of Design by Contract I stumbled upon the idea to make checks of output in comparison to input values.

The most simple example is the following:

```
toggle <- function(x)!x
```

One can immediately state that `x == !old_x` must always be true. (`old_x` stands for the value of `x` before evaluation.)

*(Of course this example is oversimplified and the postcondition does not add more useful information for humans or computers. A more useful example is on the bottom of the question..)*

So I can extend my `toggle` function as follows to check that condition with every call:

```
toggle <- function(x){
  old_x <- x
  x <- !x
  assertthat::assert_that(x == !old_x)
  return(x)
}
```

This works of course but I wondered if there's another way to access the value of `old_x` without explicitely store it (or the result) under a new name. And without splitting the postcondition-checking code to the top and bottom of the function. Something along the line of how R evaluates function calls..

One attempt I can think of is to use `sys.call` and `eval.parent` to access to the old values:

```
toggle <- function(x){
  x <- !x
  .x <- eval.parent(as.list(sys.call())[[2]])
  assertthat::assert_that(x == !.x)
  return(x)
}
```

This works, but I still need to assign a new variable `.x` and also the subsetting with `[[2]]` is not flexible yet. However writing it like `assertthat::assert_that(x == !eval.parent(as.list(sys.call())[[2]])` does not work and playing around with the search levels of `sys.call(-1 ..)` did not help.

---

Another (a bit more useful) example where the postcondition adds some information:

```
increment_if_smaller_than_2 <- function(x){
  old_x <- x
  x <- ifelse(x < 2, x <- x + 1, x)
  assertthat::assert_that(all(x >= old_x))
  return(x)
}
```

---

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the old parameter-values by accessing it via the parent environment. For this solution to work, you need to introduce new variable(s) for the return-result, i.e. retval, to prevent re-assignments to method-params. IMHO this isn't a serious drawback, since it's good programming-style not to overwrite method-parameters anyway. You could i.e. do the following:

```
test <- function(.a) {
  retval <- 2 * .a
  assertthat::assert_that(abs(retval) >= abs(.a))
  return(retval)
}

a <- 42
test(a)
# [1] 84
```

If you would like to take it a step further and submit the assertion-function dynamically you could do that as follows:

```
test_with_assertion <- function(.a, assertion) {
  retval <- 2 * .a
  assertthat::assert_that(assertion(retval, eval.parent(.a)))
  return(retval)
}

a <- 42
test_with_assertion(a, function(new_value, old_value) 
  abs(new_value) >= abs(eval.parent(old_value)) )
# [1] 84
```

Does this do, what you intended to do?